# construct setting page in windows phone 8

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, application-settings, alarms

I am developing on alarm based application
I want to add one setting page to my app. I want to change image of Image control which is on my Mainpage. image should be changing when button click event occurs from setting page. All Images are stored in my simple local folder of application like assets folder. please help me

Answer (score 0):

So you could do simply like this, within your `button` click event handler:

```
BitmapImage imgSource = new BitmapImage(
      new Uri("/PivotApp1;component/Images/halfstar.png", UriKind.Relative));
imageName.Source = null;//imageName is the name of the image control
imageName.Source = imgSource;
```

For more you could refer these:

[On Button Press - Change Image Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735294/)

[Imagebutton change source property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770527/)

To show multiple images, you could use the `image sliding`. [Reference](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Picasa_Image_Gallery_with_JSON_in_WP7)

Hope it helps!

Comment: but how to use it my button is in setting.xaml page and image control is in mainpage.xaml.
And the other thing is how can user show all images which are stored on my projects assets folder and how user can user select one image for change from all images.
please help me

Comment: So you can store the image control name in a global variable, in other words in the App.xaml.cs but make sure to have that variable as static. So that you could use that string value(the image control) in your settings.xaml.cs where you could use it within the event handler.

Comment: how to show all images which are stored on my assets folder ???
can you give a source or example like that

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an example of a settings page, check out my app templates: [Universal version](http://gregstoll.livejournal.com/452436.html) and [Silverlight (WP 8.0) version](http://gregstoll.livejournal.com/427979.html) - they both have a settings page and an example of how to respond to when a setting changes.